# GWT - How to call a JavaScript function inside another JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

I have a GWT class with two JSNI JavaScript functions. I want to call one function inside another, like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public native void Function1()
  /*-{
    console.log("Function 1");
  }-*/;

  public native void Function2()
  /*-{
    Function1();
  }-*/;
}
```

In this case, when executing `Function2` i'm getting `"Function1 is not defined"`.

Keep in mind that I don't want to embeed `Function1` inside `Function2` code, I need two different JSNI functions (so I can call `Function1` from multiple functions).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the two methods to be `static` also.
you can simply call any method from your jsni code like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static native void Function1()
  /*-{
    console.log("Function 1");
  }-*/;

  public static native void Function2()
  /*-{
    @xxx.xxxxx.xxxx.MyClass::Function1();
  }-*/;
}
```

more information can be found [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#methods-fields).

Comment: you can also call a non static function

Comment: then you have to use `this`

Comment: Thank you both, this is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
package mypackage;  

public class Account {
    private int balance = 0;

 public int add(int amt) {
      balance += amt;
   }

public native void exportAdd() /*-{
    var that = this;
    that.@mypackage.Account::add(I)(10);
}-*/;
}
```